# How to detect if IE is having JAVA blocked (security)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, applet

How to detect if IE is running with HIGHEST security and JAVA APPLET will not appear.  It seems IE does not show alternative content of java object  in this case.

I like to display some instructions to end user how to adjust their security settings *IF* java is disabled.

Is there difference in INTRANET ZONE how this works when compared to INTERNET zone?

Comment: I believe (but I'm not 100%) this is only for Microsoft's VM which is version 1.1.4. Does your applet work with version 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the [navigator.javaEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536610(VS.85).aspx) method?

There is also a [clientCaps.isComponentInstalled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531357(VS.85).aspx) method, but didn't ever used it.